# Фраза непонятна или не понятна?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Если сравнить варианты по частотности употребления, то предпочтение отдается слитному написанию (примерно 10:1): Им непонятна наша жизнь. Эта радость нам не понятна.

А как пишется: Схема денежных потоков до конца (не) понятна? Здесь возможны одна или две формы написания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни одной. По смыслу здесь возможно только ***"не до конца понятна"***.

*"До конца непонятно"* означало бы *"полностью непонятно"*, а не *"не полностью понятно"*. Ну а раздельный вариант слишком легко смешать со слитным, поэтому его лучше избегать. В русском отрицание регулярно все-таки непосредственно предшествует отрицаемому, вариант "не до конца" вполне тому соответствует, поэтому смысла экспериментировать со слитным-раздельным написанием не вижу.

Comment: Пожалуй, это лучший вариант.

Comment: Это не вариант, а единственная возможность. Был бы "вариант" - не стал бы даже упоминать, ибо так вопрос не стоит. Спрашивали о двух допустимых - я казал, что ни одного. Только в связи с этим и предложил третий. Я считаю, что нужно бережно подходить к мысли автора, а не решать за него, как надо.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что вариант до конца не/понятен - невозможен? Такой вариант тоже возможен.

Comment: Читайте мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в этом случае нужно писать раздельно.  Значение выражения - *понятна не на все 100%, не совсем.*

Слитное написание меняет смысл высказывания: *непонятна до конца* = *совсем, на все 100%.*

Answer (score 1):

Вера, Вы же знаете правило. Здесь явный утвердительный смысл, а не отрицательный.

Наречия меры и степени абсолютно, более чем, весьма, в высшей степени, крайне, настолько, необычайно, очень, полностью, почти, решительно, слишком, совершенно, удивительно, чрезвычайно и некоторые другие усиливают утвердительный смысл следующих за ними прилагательных и поэтому последние пишутся с не слитно.

Answer (score 1):

"Схема денежных потоков непонятна." - Здесь более вероятно слитное написание "непонятна".
"Схема денежных потоков до конца не понятна." - В этом случае - раздельное написание "непонятно."  (Схема не понятна в полной мере.)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за ответы.

Судя по реальным текстам, частотность выражений такова:

а)  не до конца понятно (3) – до конца не понятно(4);

б) не до конца понятна (5) – до конца не понятна  (1).

Слитного написания нет.

В принципе я согласна с тем, что язык стремится путем изменения конструкции выражения не допускать неоднозначности понимания.

Остается только неясным, **как объяснить решение задачи с помощью  формальных правил из академического справочника Лопатина.**

Comment: А зачем объяснять с помощью формальных правил? И почему именно из Лопатина? Надо сказать, что Лопатин вообще очень далек от формализации правил. Розенталь, например, куда более последователен на этом пути. Но при этом оба они явно не ставят себе такой задачи как формальная систематизация.  Ну и в конце концов, тут не в том дело, что язык к чему-то там "стремится". Тут логика высказывания. На уровне силлогизма. "Не все понятно" должно отличаться по форме от "Все непонятно" и "Все не очень понятно". Можно еще вариантов подкинуть.